# Unity C#: How to parse a json array returned as a string

Tags: unity-game-engine

can't seem to find an elegant way to deal with this!

lets say i have a method that returns a json array like this ["3","4","5"] as a **string** in Unity

how do i read or work with each item (3, 4, and 5) individually? (with each item as an **integer**, not string)

Comment: Have you tried deserializing the json string?

Comment: is there a definitive guide for this? there seems to be many types of methods

Comment: There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity) that outlines how to serialize/deserialize json in unity.

Answer (score 0):

hey all i found my preferred simple solution

```
public string[] arrayOfString;

string response = "["1","2","3"]" // alternatively you would get this when json array returned ["1","2","3"]

response = response.Trim('[', ']'); // "1","2","3"
response = response.Replace("\"", ""); // 1,2,3

arrayOfString = response.Split(','); // becomes an array of string

arrayOfString[0] // returns 1
```

for array of Int from String

```
public Int[] arrayOfInt;

string response = "["1","2","3"]" // alternatively you would get this when json array returned ["1","2","3"]

response = response.Trim('[', ']'); // "1","2","3"
response = response.Replace("\"", ""); // 1,2,3

arrayOfInt = Array.ConvertAll(response.Split(','), int.Parse); // to create array of integers from string

arrayOfInt[0] // returns 1
```

Comment: If you are going to use JSON for more than just one array you should definitely use a library to serialize/deserialize JSON in C# like: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json